# How to instantiate a class when its property members are not of primitive types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

1) Let's say I've a class MyDataInfo:

```
public class MyDataInfo
{
  public int MyDataInfoID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

For the purpose of the functionality I'm after, I've created another class (**MyData**) whose property members are of MyDataInfo type.

2) Here's MyData

```
public class MyData
{
  public MyDataInfo Prop1 { get; set; }
  public MyDataInfo Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

3) And, here's my action method

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  MyData myObject = new MyData();
  return View(myObject);
}
```

4) Finally, this in my View template (which is **strongly typed** and **inherits from MyData**)

```
<%= Html.Encode (Model.Prop1.Name) %>
<%= Html.Encode (Model.Prop2.Name) %>
```

Unfortunately, I got an error "**Object not set to an instance of an object**."

Am I missing something or is there a different way of obtaining the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've instantiated `MyData`, but not `Prop1` and `Prop2` which you are trying to access in the view (`Prop1` is null, so `Model.Prop1.Name` will throw an exception). You will need to instantiate these properties:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var myObject = new MyData 
    {
        Prop1 = new MyDataInfo(),
        Prop2 = new MyDataInfo()
    };
    return View(myObject);
}
```

This could also be done in the constructor of MyData:

```
public class MyData
{
    public void MyData()
    {
        Prop1 = new MyDataInfo();
        Prop2 = new MyDataInfo();
    }

    public MyDataInfo Prop1 { get; set; }
    public MyDataInfo Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 - good answer. I really do have to find a time slot when you and some others are not glued to SO so I can get some answers in. ;-)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov -- you are lways prompt to help others. Thanks a lot for help.